# Named MetaPost instances in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, metapost

Is there anything similar to ConTeXt's \defineMPinstance for LuaLaTeX? I need to be able to have several MetaPost instances with their own sets of variables, something like this:

```
\begin[instance_one]{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
        a := 1cm;
        draw fullcircle scaled a; % 1cm circle
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin[instance_two]{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
        a := 2cm;
        draw fullcircle scaled a; % 2cm circle
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin[instance_one]{mplibcode}
    beginfig(2);
        draw unitsquare scaled a; % 1cm square
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin[instance_two]{mplibcode}
    beginfig(2);
        draw unitsquare scaled a; % 2cm circle
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
```

Comment: Looking at [the current docs](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) I think the answer is "No, there is nothing like that in luamplib" -- it is either nothing shared between any `mplibcode` environment or everything shared, depending on your option settings.   

But I would say it is a reasonable thing to ask for as an enhancement on [the mailing list](https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/metapost)

Comment: @Thruston Thank you! Probably, I'll do just that. It occurred to me as well that there's currently no such thing in luamplib. I thought that maybe there's some other package which has something like this or that there may be some easy-to-implement workaround.

Comment: Submitted an issue on GH https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues/99 . A fairly minor modification to the Lua code seems to do the trick and updating the LaTeX interface should be trivial, but I'm not sure that the easy solution won't break some other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for named MetaPost instances [was added](https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/commit/07579a09cdb85b4868874b60297fcaa7f0a70986) in luamplib 2.22.0. Syntax is almost as described in the question:

```
\begin{mplibcode}[instanceOne]
    beginfig(1);
        a := 1cm;
        draw fullcircle scaled a; % 1cm circle
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin{mplibcode}[instanceOne]
    beginfig(1);
        draw unitsquare scaled a; % 1cm square
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
```

UPD:
Also, the support for per-instance `\everymplib` and `\everyendmplib` [was added](https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues/102). It works like this:

```
\everymplib[instanceOne]{instance := 1; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib[instanceOne]{endfig;}
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for suggesting this.